# Ipython QtConsole %edit

Tags: edit, ipython, qtconsole

When using the magic function %edit from QtConsole with IPython, the call does not block, and does not execute the saved code. It does however save a temporary file...

I think this is intended behavior due to GUI editors and uncertainty, and whatever that reason is for not being able to communicate with subprocess (pyZMQ?).

What do you suggest as the best way to mix %edit/%run magics?

I would not mind calling two different commands (one to edit, and one after I have saved and execution is safe). But those commands need a way to synchronize this target file location, or someone to persist storage, and probably need some crude form of predicatably generating filenames such that you can edit more than one file at a time, and execute in arbitrarily. Session persistence is not a must.

Would writing my own magic do any good? Hope we can %edit macros soon, that would do well enough to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shoudl be able to do `%edit filename.py` and `%run filename.py`. The non blocking behavior is expected, and IIRC due to technical reason. Not unsurmountable  but difficult.

You could define your own magic if you wish, improvement are welcomed.

> Hope we can %edit macros soon, that would do well enough to make it work.

For that too, PR are welcomed. I guess as a workaround/option you can `%load macro` which would put macro on input n+1 , edit it and redefine it, that might be a good extension for a cell magic `%%macro macroname`

Comment: The reason I mentioned '%edit macro' is because of the corresponding '%save macroname filename.ipy'. My preference would be to keep my input clean as possible and keep the mess in %edit. What I like about %edit macro is the use of temporary file *automagically* (so I dont have to be burdened with paths and filenames).

Answer (score 0):

If you have some executable code on your input (from QtConsole), you can type

```
%edit 1-5
```

This fires the editor, creates a temporarily file (automatically managed), and loads your input lines. This is nearly enough, now how to retrieve the name of that temp file pragmatically?

I see the print statement on Stdout, but its not visible to QtConsole AFAIK. Could maybe redirect stdout to catch that line, but that may not be an option anyway if your doing something else with stdout.

If I could retrieve the full pathname that was just created, this would be cake.  Store it where some magics will know how to find it. Then issue a followup command when ready,pops the name off the stack, loads it into a macro, and run. All this with 2 input commands and no names to remember (unless you want to find and use that macro again, but for 1 shot stuff...)

How do I catch or retrieve the path of that temporary file?